# How to get the property name as a string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My simple example:

```
let a = { foo : 5}, b = { stuff : 7};
let func = function(obj, prop) { ++obj[prop]; }
func(a, 'foo');
func(b, 'stuff');
```

When I call `func` I set the property name as string literal directly. If I want to rename the property late (in my code source) then I have to change the string literal too. Is it possible to get the property name as a string in runtime instead of using the string value as a literal?

**UPD** (for clarity)

In my project, I have some classes each of them has a property which contains an array. But this property has the different name for each class. I have a logic for handling these arrays content. This logic is the same for each class. Right now I pass the property name as a string literal, but if I later rename these properties in my code source then I must to change and the string literals too. If I forget to do it I will have a problem. So I want to get rid of the use of string literals in this task.

Comment: Do you always pass the function an object with a single property? in that case, it would be easy. Otherwise… how could the function know which property is the right one to use?

Comment: *> it would be easy.*
?
*> how could the function know which property is the right one to use?* 
by the property name.

Comment: Yeah but you said the property can be renamed. If you pass an object with two properties and no property name, how does the function know which property to increment?

Comment: I meant the renaming in my code source. :)

Comment: So rename it both in the object definition and the function call.

Comment: a.foo++; b.stuff++;

Comment: I think the reason no one has sufficiently answered your question is that it's difficult to think of a situation in which one would need to change these string literals very often. That would normally be something you code once, and finish. If you have a huge number of keys and they are changing all the time, you should look into typescript's "enum" to create a set of string definitions as constants that you can use for both the keys and the things you pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is a bad idea. If something behaves the same in different objects, call it the same name. But hey, there's an ES6 concept for that!

Symbols are used by JavaScript to support similar behaviour in different "classes". So let's do that here.

Let's create a Symbol:

```
const incrementableProp = Symbol("incrementableProp")
```

First, let's store the name of the property in your object that should have the behaviour:

```
const a = {
    specialProp: [],
    [incrementableProp]: "specialProp"
}
```

The Symbol itself will always be the same, so the increment function can find it reliably:

```
function incrementProp(obj) {
    if(incrementableProp in obj)
        obj[obj[incrementableProp]]++
    else throw new TypeError("This object does not support an incremental property.")
}
```

Lastly, let's make sure you need to change the name only once by removing the Symbol definition in the object. We'll use a decorator for that:

```
function special(target, key, descriptor) {
    target[incrementableProp] = key
    return descriptor
}
```

So now you can do this:

```
const a = {
    @special specialProp: []
}
```

Comment: I know it. How can it help me in my case?

Comment: Well, if the object has a single property, it will be incremented without the need to pass its name the the function. So that solves your problem if your objects have a single property.

Comment: I added **UPD** section. I have a hope it will be clearer for my question description.

Comment: @AndreyBushman here you go (with some esnext if you're using a transpiler, otherwise ignore the decorator bit at the end).